# Archive file inside of folders

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to do the following, we have a list of folders for example and want to make archive in the same directory as the xml files locations:

Folder 1

- subfolder 1

  - XML File 1
  - XML File 2
- subfolder 2

  - XML File 1
  - XML File 2
- subfolder 3

  - XML File 1
  - XML File 2

What I want to accomplish is the following, I want to archive in each sub folder the xml files that are older than 30 days in monthly archives.

Folder 1

- subfolder 1

  - XML File 1
  - XML File 2
  - archive-mar-2020.zip
  - archive-feb-2020.zip
- subfolder 2

  - XML File 1
  - XML File 2
  - archive-mar-2020.zip
  - archive-feb-2020.zip

This is what I have now, so somehow I need to change the target path to the current folder or something but I don't know how to do this

```
# set folder path
$log_path = "F:\test\*.xml"
$zip_path = "F:\test\*.7z"
$target_path = "F:\test-zip\"

# set min age of files
$max_days = "-30"
$delete_max_days = "-365"

# get the current date
$curr_date = Get-Date

# determine how far back we go based on current date
$zip_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)
$delete_zip_date = $curr_date.AddDays($delete_max_days)

#$zip_date = (Get-Date).AddMonths(0).Month

# filter files
Get-ChildItem $log_path -Recurse | Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)}|

    ForEach {
    $Zip = $target_path + "{0:MMM}_{0:yyyy}.7z" -f $_.LastWriteTime
    & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -mx9 -t7z -m0=lzma2  $Zip $_.FullName |Out-Null
    If ($LastExitCode -eq 0) { Remove-Item $_.FullName }
    }

$deletefile = Get-ChildItem $zip_path | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $delete_zip_date } | Remove-Item
```

Comment: At first glance: you are creating strings for `$max_days` and `$delete_max_days`, where they should be integers. Remove the quotes there

Answer (score 0):

**This is untested**

I think you need to get the list of subfolders first and iterating over that, find the xml files in each subfolder.

Group the files on the formatted LastWriteTime (MMM-yyyy) property and base the archive name on that.

Something like:

```
# set folder paths
$log_path    = "F:\test"
$zip_path    = "F:\test"
$target_path = "F:\test-zip"

# set min age of files
$max_days = -30
$delete_max_days = -365

# get the current date
$curr_date = (Get-Date).Date

# determine how far back we go based on current date
$zip_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)
$delete_zip_date = $curr_date.AddDays($delete_max_days)

# first get a list of subfolders full names
$subDirs = (Get-ChildItem -Path $log_path -Directory -Recurse).FullName
foreach ($subFolder in $subDirs) {
    # within each subfolder, get the xml files
    Get-ChildItem -Path $subFolder -Filter '*.xml' -File -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $zip_date } |
    Group-Object @{Expression = '{0:MMM-yyyy}' -f $_.LastWriteTime } |
    ForEach-Object {
        # $_.Name is the name of the group, which is the formatted LastWriteTime
        $zipFile = Join-Path -Path $target_path -ChildPath "archive-$($_.Name).7z"
        foreach ($file in $_.Group) {
            & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -mx9 -t7z -m0=lzma2  $zipFile $_.FullName | Out-Null
            if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) { Remove-Item $_.FullName }
        }
    }

}

$deletefile = Get-ChildItem -Path $zip_path -Filter '*.7z' -File | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $delete_zip_date } | Remove-Item
```